# Parsing XML from a online feed using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

How can I get data from a XML feed? Look my sample below:

http://jsfiddle.net/3se101uf/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.get('http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeList&a=thunderbay', function (d) {
    $('body').append('<dl />');

    $(d).find('route').each(function () {

        var $route = $(this);
        var tag = $route.find("tag").text();;
        var title = $route.find("title").text();;

        var html = '<dt> </dt>';
        html += '< p> ' + tag + ' - ' + title '< /p>';
        html += '</dd>';

        $('dl').append($(html));
        console.log(d);

    });
}); });
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeList&a=thunderbay', function (xml) {
        $('route', xml).each(function (index, route) {
            var tag = $(route).attr('tag');
            var title = $(route).attr('title');

            $('#dl').append(
                $(document.createElement('dt'))
                    .append(
                        $(document.createElement('p'))
                            .text(tag + ' - ' + title)
                    )
            );
        });

    });
});
```

updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/3se101uf/2/)

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck in this XML for hours.

Comment: Hi again Alex, I hope you can help me again. How can I make one of these 'texts elements' be linkable?

Comment: Create a link and put it somewhere on the page... read about link and attributes you can here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp. So I would suggest to create ne link element $(document.createElement('a')), assign necessary properties and put it to the 'p' emenlt that you already have.

Comment: But is it possible to create a different link from each one of the <p> elements? Like generate a automatic link name from each element.